# How to add extra space to div using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on the sticky menu and highlight menu based on div id in WordPress. I have completed code well but I got a problem.
I have a sticky header when I click menu item in side sticky menu title going back to header title not visible.
[image]

I want result like this.'
[image]
How can I solve this?

**My Jquery Code**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    /**
     * This part causes smooth scrolling using scrollto.js
     * We target all a tags inside the nav, and apply the scrollto.js to it.
     */
    $("#nav a").click(function(evn){
        evn.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash); 
    });

    var aChildren = jQuery("#nav li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = jQuery(aChild).attr('href');
      console.log(ahref);
        aArray.push(ahref);
    } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

 $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop()+70; // get the offset of the window from the top of page
console.log('Window Position:'+windowPos);
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = $(document).height();


        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
          //console.log(theID);
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-150; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
          console.log('Div Position:'+divPos);
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question          
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
            }
        }

        if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
            if (!$("#nav li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
                var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
                $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                $("#nav li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to offset the height of the heading when you jump to an anchored section.

Are you using the jQuery scrollTo plugin? If you can do something like:

```
$("#nav a").click(function(evn){
    evn.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, 800, {offset: {top:-80, left:0} }); 
});
```

Options for scrollTo found here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: It's working for me Thanks. Can you give some explanation about this code little confused to understand?

Comment: Have a read of the scrollTo plugins docs, specifically Usage and Settings. The plugin can be used like this `$(element).scrollTo(target[,duration][,settings]);` where settings is an object and we can add the `offset` property and object which allows us to add an offset from the target element